# How to create add-ins for Outlook Web App Exchange 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, office365, outlook-addin, outlook-web-app, outlook-web-addins

I got a requirement to create some Add-Ins for Outlook Web App (OWA) Exchange 2013. I've tried googling but couldn't find much. Can someone help me on this and share some good information of links so that I can get some idea about this or at least how to start.

I've idea about Visual Studio and C#, is there any way to create these add-ins using VS tool?

Please share some links or steps, how can I create my own add-ins and how can I plug them in OWA Exchange 2013?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can build add-ins using Visual Studio or the [Yeoman generator](https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office).  Note though that you can't use C#; Office web add-ins are effectively just web pages and can be built with standard web dev tools (JavaScript, HTML5 and CSS) and various frameworks (Angular, React, etc.) but not managed .NET languages.

The best way to get started is with the "get started page":

https://dev.outlook.com/MailAppsGettingStarted/GetStarted

Also see:

Add-in dev reference: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/outlook-add-ins

Mailbox API reference: https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/

Code samples: https://dev.outlook.com/Samples/Addins

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I am looking for Outlook Web Acces (OWA) not the desktop. All the link that you have provided are related to desktop app only.

Comment: No, those resources are related to web add-ins (which run in OWA or Outlook Online). Check them again

Comment: I saw snaps in these links and thought they are desktop related. Thank you.

Comment: Correct except the part "but not managed .NET languages." . You can build a Outlook Web AddIn with any web development technology. I used 'Outlook Web AddIn' Template from Visual Studio with C# on server side code as well as MySQL database and my XML manifest points to the Controller/Actions in my app.